# GLSL 1.10 - 25 input booleans for shader

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx, glsl, shader

I'm currently writing a shader (Java/LibGDX/OpenGL ES) which needs an input of 25 booleans for the desired functionality. Since the shader should work on nearly every Android device I'm limited to OpenGL ES 2.0 (GLSL version 1.10) which makes things quite hard. OpenGL ES 3.0  requires Android 4.3+ while OpenGL ES 2.0 is available from Android 2.2.

At first I tried to reduce the amount of data given to the GPU by using a single integer which is filled by bit operations through Java. The shader then checks for the needed flags ("booleans") with the help of bit operations. Once coding was done I realized that bit-operations are supported in GLSL version 1.3 and above, so I can't use them for my purpose.

Second try was to use an array with the length 25. This increases the amount of data which needs to be loaded onto the GPU but it's not working as well. I get the following error:

```
Shader compilation failed!
From Vertex Shader:
Error: varying variables do not fit in 16 vectors.
From Fragment Shader:
Error: varying variables do not fit in 16 vectors.
```

I could not find out what this means exacly, but I think I'm limited to arrays with size <= 16.

Multidimensional Arrays are available from GLSL 1.2 so `array[5][5]` is not possible as well.

Of course I could use 25 uniforms but that seems like a pretty weird solution.

**TL;DR**

What's the best way to send the data (25 booleans / flags) to the fragment shader if I'm limited to GLSL 1.10 and OpenGL ES 2.0?

Comment: Where you use the values in the GLSL code, are you accessing them with constant indices? Or are the indices variables/expressions? You could potentially use an array of 7 `vec4` values, which is similar to an `[7][4]` array. I'll have to think about it to see if I can come up with anything better, but you're really stretching the limits of ES 2.0 here.

Comment: In fact it would work since I access the "array" with indices which are calculated right before the array access. However the answer provided by Phil Anderson is a lot simpler and less 'hacky'.

Comment: Well, that's the obvious approach, but it won't work as posted. See my comment there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep the approach of encoding them into an integer, but instead of using bitwise operations, simply do an integer divide by the bit you want to check, and modulo 2.

e.g. Say our bit pattern was 101101...

```
Bit values: 32  16  8   4   2   1
Bits:       1   0   1   1   0   1
                    ^
```

To check whether the 8 bit is set, simply divide by 8 and mod the result by 2.

101101 = 45 in decimal
45 /  8 = 5
5 mod 2 = 1, which is the answer!

Doing the same for the 16 bit would give (45 / 16) mod 2 = 0

Simples!

Comment: Thanks, this is a really good solution since it's really close to the original bit-operation idea and does not require any hacky workarounds. I will use it.

+1 for simplicity.

Comment: There is no modulo operator in the GLSL version the OP wants to use. Also, no power or shift operators, so getting value `8` to retrieve bit 3 is not straightforward.

Comment: I have not tried it yet, but according to [this document](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.Full.1.10.59.pdf) there are pow and modulo functions (see 8.2 'Exponential Functions' and 8.3 'Common Functions')
So you are right, there are no operators for this, but functions which will do the magic as well.

Comment: @RetoKoradi - I tried it now and it's working. As I said there are no operators but the functions did the job. The calculation is: 

`int val = int(bitmap / pow(2.0, index));` 
`int v = int(mod(val, 2));` 

v is 0 or 1 then.

Comment: @MaxK I missed the functions. Weird that the `mod()` function is defined, and the `%` operator is reserved for future use. It looks like the second argument of `mod()` needs to be float, so you should use `2.0` instead of `2`. In ES 2.0, there are not automatic type conversions, even though some GLSL  compilers let you get away with it without error.

Comment: @RetoKoradi just to finish this here: I changed the `2` to `2.0` and it kinda worked. The problem is: Even if i call `precision highp float` the presition of float is not good enough (at least I think) to have the binary representation I need in order to 'extract' bits with the calculation. The first few bits work just fine, the other bits seem to have a random value. I worked this around by using 2 floats until I find a better solution.

Comment: @MaxK A standard 32-bit float uses 23 bits for the mantissa. So depending on how you count, you get 23/24 bits of relative precision. `highp` values may typically be 32-bit floats, even tough they are only guaranteed to have 16 bits of relative precision in GLSL 1.00.

Comment: @RetoKoradi So it's not enough, no matter what I do. I _might_ be able to reduce the needed data but that would require a big change in shader code. Thanks for clearing things, I think I have to add this to my TODOs.